# Filtering by dates saved as strings in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm developing a program in Java that saves medical information of employees, and within it, there is the date of the last medical studies they have done. The dates are saved in a SQL database as String with the format "dd/MM/yyyy". So at some point, the program needs to filter only those whose last medical studies were one year ago or more to be deployed in a JTable.

I'm looking for a SQL command to filter them and that can be globally used in different types of SQL Servers. Right now I'm using SQLite but I want the statement to work the same in MySQL by saving the dates as Strings in the column. This is because the infrastructure of the workplace is poor and the internet is really bad, that's why I'm using SQLite but if this problem is solved, the idea is to change to MySQL with very few changes in the code.

The program already filters them with an algorithm that returns the period of time between the last medical study and the current date, but I want an SQL statement so I don't have to recover all the information and deploying only those whose period is more than or equal to a year.

I've been searching for ways to cast the String into a date and then returning those whose period is 1-year or more but none of them worked properly.

Comment: You fell victim to one of the classic blunders, the most famous of which is “Never get involved in a land war in Asia,” but only slightly less well known is this: "Never put dates in a column with varchar as the type!”

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I know I would only use dateformat but in SQLite i can't

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: Also, if you _must_ use strings to store you date, as least use the ISO-8601 standard, which is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that might seems to work, but the format "dd/MM/yyyy is user friendly for its purpose, so what i should is to save it with the SO-8601 standard in the database and deploying it and be used by the user with the dd/MM/yyyy format somehow

Comment: If you store the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` in SQLite, then you can easily convert it to any other format, but not  the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the right answer - use the ISO 8601 format.

If you *still* want to keep the dates in dd/MM/yyyy format, then you'll need to complicate your `SELECT`s to convert the date in something that, while still a string, has a lexicographic order that is date-compatible (which means something much more like ISO-8601).

Select dates after 14/02/2019:

...WHERE (SUBSTR(dateaschar, 7, 4)||SUBSTR(dateaschar, 4, 2)||SUBSTR(dateaschar, 1, 2)) > '20190214';

Comment: So i've tried this and it works properly, despite the messy of the code it will be easier to implement to the entire program without many changes. the only thing is that im not getting the logic within the dateaschar substrating the dates, i mean, the SUBSTR(dateaschar, 7, 4) should extract the year on a dd/MM/yyyy format but the yyyy is between the 6-10 index in the String

Comment: nevermind, i just checked and i got the logic, its substract 7 from the index starting at 1 and 4 is the number of chars is gonna get after that

Answer (score 1):

> Right now im using SQLite but i want the statement to work the same in MySQL by saving the dates as Strings in the column.

What is universal is the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Instead of dd/MM/yyyy it's yyyy-mm-dd. August 9th, 2020 is 2020-08-09. If you use ISO 8601 you can store them the same in both SQLite and MySQL. Most everything accepts ISO 8601.

You can also declare the column as `datetime` in both MySQL and SQLite. SQLite will store it as a string, but both will accept and use the ISO 8601 format.

```
create table foo (
    created_at datetime
);

insert into foo (created_at) values ('2020-08-09');
```

So at least that part will work.

> I'm looking for an SQL code to filter them and that can be globally use in different types of SQL Servers.

Unfortunately, date functions are not part of the SQL standard. Not even simple formatting: SQLite uses `strftime` and MySQL uses `date_format`. There is some overlap in the formatting, but not a lot.

Beyond that, you have `date` to get just the date part, `time` to get just the time part, and that's about it.

```
select date(created_at) from foo;
+------------------+
| date(created_at) |
+------------------+
| 2020-08-09       |
+------------------+
```

SQL databases have many quirks, MySQL more so. I would strongly suggest to pick a SQL server and stick to it. MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL (which I recommend) are all freely available.

You can also handle the formatting in your view layer. Fetch timestamps as ISO 8601, feed the data to your view layer, and let it do the formatting. This is more flexible. Most everything will work with ISO 8601 and it leaves the formatting decisions up to your user interface designer (even if that's you).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for SQL Server

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(dbField, 7, 4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(dbField, 4, 2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(dbField, 1, 2))
```

suppose

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('25-08-2017', 7, 4)+'/'+SUBSTRING('25-08-2017', 4, 2)+'/'+SUBSTRING('25-08-2017', 1, 2))

        
showing #
2017-08-25 00:00:00.000
```

in condition

```
where DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(dbField, 7, 4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(dbField, 4, 2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(dbField, 1, 2)))>=1
```